# Creating new instance of the class from class it extends in PHP

Tags: php, class, extends

I'm coding a big script in PHP that's require to be safe from future user-created extensions to it.
I figured out to create something like permissions class checking extension access to some core variables etc.

Here is the startup class:

```
class SystemStartup
{   
    private function startClass ( ) {
        require ( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/sys.run.php' );   
         //starting SystemRun with something like core security token
        new SystemRun ( hash ( 'sha256' , $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . microtime ( TRUE ) ) );
    }
    function __construct ( ) {  
        //here i have some security stuff like checking class not already running
        $this -> startClass ( );
    }
    function __destruct ( ) {
        //wywolane na samym koncu
    }

};
```

SystemRun class:

```
class SystemRun
{   
    private     $SystemToken;

    //static because i want to be callable from other classes extending SystemRun
    protected static    $SystemUrlControl;

    private function startClass ( ) {

        //before more code

        //loading file with child class
        require ( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/urlcontrol.php' );
        //starting it with security token
        echo $this -> SystemToken; //just for check
        self :: $SystemUrlControl = new SystemUrlControl ( $this -> SystemToken );  

        //more more more code (its main class)
    }
    protected function validateToken ( $SystemToken ) {
        echo $this -> SystemToken; //just for check
        //this should check tokens are the same
        if ( $this -> SystemToken == $SystemToken ) return TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    }
    function __construct ( $SystemToken ) { 
        //saving token for next classes
        $this -> SystemToken = $SystemToken;
        $this -> startClass ( );
    }
};
```

And now SystemUrlControl with extends SystemRun

```
class SystemUrlControl extends SystemRun
{   
    private         $SystemToken;

    //functions

    //more functions

    //more more more

    function __construct ( $SystemToken ) { 
        if ( !parent :: validateToken ( $SystemToken ) ) echo 'somebody else called me!';
        $this -> SystemToken = $SystemToken;
    }
};
```

The problem is that calling validateToken from `SystemUrlControl` returning `FALSE` - SystemRun see it own SystemToken as NULL.

Output (from echo) is:

```
> 5b6a09d8f03dd7e6229a5... (valid token) (here NULL value) somebody else called me!
```

Comment: `self :: $SystemToken` is not a static member, and thus has to be used with `$this->SystemToken`.

Comment: Its one "ctrl+z" less then changes when debugging ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your validateToken method you have this.

```
$this -> $SystemToken
```

It should be

```
$this -> SystemToken
```

Comment: That mistake is likely caused by the strange formatting (with spaces between `$this->` and `self::` and the member variables/functions.

Comment: Yes, its just mistake when writing code here :) In files i have $this -> SystemToken. Thanks :)